# rails fb_graph notification fails because of ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fb-graph

Trying to post a notification in fb_graph gem and rails 3.2. We have done like the docs describe at https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/wiki/notifications:

```
user = FbGraph::User.new('matake')
app = FbGraph::Application.new(APP_ID, :secret => APP_SECRET)

app.notify!(
  user,
  :href => 'http://matake.jp',
  :template => 'Your friend @[12345] achieved new badge!'
)
```

and alternative way:

```
user.notification!(
  :access_token => APP_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  :href => 'http://matake.jp',
  :template => 'Your friend @[12345] achieved new badge!'
)
```

both returns 
 `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Is it required a SSL conection? Is there a workaround?